# Get the currently played <audio> file on a page with multiple audio files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have multiple audio files on a page and I am hoping to get the playing audio file through JQuery.

This is what I tried but it only gets the first one:

```
 var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
      audio.addEventListener('play', function() { 
        console.log($(this));            
 });
```

Is it possible for me to get only the audio file on the page that is currently playing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach to this problem would be to query all audio elements in the document, and then iterate over those to find the first instance where `ispasued` is not truthy:

```
function getCurrentlyPlayingAudio() {

  for(const audio of document.querySelectorAll('audio')) {

    if(!audio.paused) {
      return audio;
    } 
  }  

  // return undefined if no such audio element found
}
```

This solution uses the native [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method to query audio elements, and is therefore not dependant on jQuery.

To then query the 'current playing audio element' after an audio element has started playing, you could use the proposed method in the following way:

```
document.querySelectorAll('audio').forEach(audio => {

    audio.addEventListener('play', () => {

        const currentPlaying = getCurrentlyPlayingAudio();
        console.log('current playing audio:', currentPlaying);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, when I play the audio, this function doesn't run. I am hoping to run this function everytime I play an audio and I should be able to get the playing <audio> element.

Comment: @Steve you're welcome - just extended the answer. Does this help?

Comment: thanks. I also changed my original answer a bit and that worked. I am accepting your answer though. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,

I also changed my original answer a bit and that worked.

```
var audList = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");

      for (var i = 0; i < audList.length; i++) {
          audList[i].addEventListener("play", onPlay, false);
          audList[i].addEventListener("ended", onEnded, false);
      }
      function onPlay(e) {
          console.log(e.target.id + " Well hello there!");
          console.log($(this));

      };
      function onEnded(e) {
          console.log(e.target.id + " Left this audio.");
      };
```